# Обособление местоимения «такой»

Tags: пунктуация

*В руке — лишь горстка почти предельно уплотнённых, и теперь таких обоюдоострых, таких ещё давно засахаренных, и всё ещё липнущих, таких паточно-тягучих останочных минут, прежде чем полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием, и потеряю голову.*

Каковы правила обособления местоимения "таких" на письме? В каких случаях запятая ставится, а в каких - нет?

Comment: Приведите примеры, без них сложно понять, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: В руке — лишь горстка почти предельно уплотнённых, и теперь таких обоюдоострых, таких ещё давно засахаренных, и всё ещё липнущих, таких паточно-тягучих останочных минут, прежде чем полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием, и потеряю голову.

Answer (score 1):

*В руке — лишь горстка почти предельно уплотнённых и теперь **таких** обоюдоострых, **таких** уже давно засахаренных и всё ещё липнущих, **таких** паточно-тягучих останочных минут...*

1. В приведенном предложении **обособления нет**.

**ТАКОЙ**,  I. **местоим. прил**. 2. Выражает **сильную степень свойства, состояния или усиления оценки.** Т. красивый. Т-ая глупая. Он т. силач! Т-ая тоска на сердце! Не стоит думать о таких пустяках. Т-ая досада! Раздался т. гром, что все испугались.

2. Обособление возможно в предложениях, где местоимение ***такой*** является указательном словом. Это СПП с  определительными придаточными, местоименная пара ***такой...какой.*** Или местоименно-союзная связь: ***такой...будто, такой...как, такой...что.***

*Минуты были **такие**, каких не было никогда. Минуты были **такие,** будто все происходило во сне.*

Также сравнительный оборот: *Минуты были ***такие***, как во сне.*